French movie about a group of people who gamble with death
I saw a French movie back in 1998, but the movie may have been older.
I can't recall everything, but the story is about a secret group of people that have meetings in unknown places where they would gamble about who was going to die or get hurt in some way.
One scene I can't forget was when they (5-6 people) were in a forest with big but sparse trees. Then they then put on blindfolds, and started to run for their lives. Most of them smashed into trees and got really hurt.
I have been searching for this movie for the last 10 years, so any suggestion is welcome!

You are looking for the Spanish movie Intacto from 2001.

the film depicts an underground trade in luck, where fortune flows from those who have less to those who have more; the premise purports that luck can be amassed and transferred as any other commodity. The story follows several participants as they engage in literal games of chance, each one more risky than the last, to eliminate the unlucky.

You can see the scene in the woods in the trailer at around 1:00




Yes, that's the one.
Thank you!
